# Sql Statement: How do I get the highest rating and the product for each location?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

How do I get the highest rating and the product for each location? This is more to sql statement. Can anyone please help to spot where is the error? It doesn't retrieve the values I wanted.

*Using Mysql database

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT r.rating,
       r.product,
       l.places,
       l.address,
       l.telephone,
       l.lng,
       l.lat
FROM   locations AS l
       LEFT JOIN ratings AS r
         ON l.places = r.places
ORDER  BY r.rating DESC
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What about more than one product with highest rating?

Comment: ....now you lay down the "MySql" info !!!!

Comment: That's more a :( than a :)

Answer (score 1):

Since, you haven't mentioned the database server you are using, the query below will work on almost all RDBMS including `MySQL`

```
SELECT  r.rating, 
        r.product, 
        l.places, 
        l.address, 
        l.telephone, 
        l.lng, 
        l.lat 
FROM    locations AS l 
        INNER JOIN ratings AS r 
            ON l.places = r.places 
        (
            SELECT  a.places, b.product, MAX(b.rating) max_rating
            FROM    locations a
                    INNER JOIN ratings b
                        ON a.places = b.places 
            GROUP   BY a.places, b.product
        ) c ON l.places = c.places AND
                r.product = c.product AND
                r.rating = c.max_Rating
ORDER   BY r.rating desc
```

OR if your RDBMS supports *window functions*,

```
SELECT  rating, product,  places, 
        address,  telephone,  lng,  lat
FROM
    (
        SELECT  r.rating, r.product,  l.places, 
                l.address,  l.telephone,  l.lng,  l.lat 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.product,  l.places
                                    ORDER BY r.rating DESC) rn
        FROM    locations AS l 
                INNER JOIN ratings AS r 
                    ON l.places = r.places 
    )   x
WHERE   x.rn = 1    
ORDER   BY rating desc
```

Comment: He did mention MySQL but the window function solution is much nicer, kudos for adding it.

Answer (score 1):

assuming later version of sql-server. This is not tested - I'm a little unsure about the correct partition ...either `l.places` or `r.product`. Try this...

```
;WITH cte
    as
    (
    SELECT     
               r.rating,
           r.product,
           l.places,
           l.address,
           l.telephone,
           l.lng,
           l.lat,
           [rnk] = RANK OVER(PARTITION BY l.places ORDER BY r.rating DESC)
    FROM   locations AS l
           LEFT JOIN ratings AS r
             ON l.places = r.places
    )
SELECT
        rating,
        product,
        places,
        address,
        telephone,
        lng,
        lat
FROM cte
WHERE [rnk] = 1
ORDER  BY rating DESC
```

Comment: You should start using more standard compatible syntax. `... AS .. rnk` instead of `rnk = ` and the semicolon should go to the end: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ...rubbish!! Look in [here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist) and do a search for "OrderCount = ":  In terms of square brackets Aaron does not use them but is not concerned if other do. I realise that MS are deprecating _not_ using semi-colons but the chances are that if I put a sem-colon at the end of my answer which includes a CTE then the OPwe will encounter an error ..... in my production stored procedures I finish all SQL statements with `;`

Comment: Defining a column alias using "rnk = " is non standard syntax. I think it's better to use SQL standard syntax rather than some vendor specific dialect if the standard offers identical functionality and doesn't have any side effect. (I don't mean the dreaded square brackets but `foo = x` as opposed to `x as foo`. The link was only to explain why it's better to always use a semicolon at the end - they way every other SQL based DBMS works. If everyone had used semicolons at the end right from the start there never would have been the need to write them *before* a statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I basically use [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist) as my `standard`. Please refer to the section "Using column aliases" as to why I prefer `foo = x`. If there's a set of world-wide standards that I'm missing please refer me to them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name totally understand about semi-colons. In terms of `x as foo` or `foo = x` I tend towards @AaronBertrands viewpoint; reason being if I have many columns in select clause and use `=` then I can align the `=` and it is then more readable what columns are included....using your _"standard"_ we could potentially have `thisIsAReallyLooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongggggggggggggggField AS LongField` with the `AS Longfield` text not even visible in the IDE !

Comment: "*If there's a set of world-wide standards*". Yes there is, it's called the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the help on this; to avoid any future pain I should follow `ANSI-92 SQL syntax` - I think I'm probably 95% there already; can't find a link on my web search to a document that lays out these standards though - do you have a link please or a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

SQL-Server version (2005 and greater):

```
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT r.rating, 
                r.product, 
                l.places, 
                l.address, 
                l.telephone, 
                l.lng, 
                l.lat, 
                RN = Rank() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY l.places 
                         ORDER BY rating DESC) 
         FROM   locations AS l 
                INNER JOIN ratings AS r 
                        ON l.places = r.places 
SELECT *  FROM   x  WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: +1 oi!! - i did (almost) that first! Although I left a `LEFT JOIN` in which I'm now doubting?

Comment: @whytheq: `LEFT JOIN` select all records even if there's no record on the right side (you could also write `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which is clearer but the same).